# Is it possible to define PHP variables in a for loop using $i?

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

I am looking to do something like the following:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$number_of_bundles; $i++) {

    $rug_size . $i = $_POST['Size' . $i];

}
```

Unfortunately this does not work since I get "undefined index" and when I try echoeing, for example, $rug_size1 is undefined.

How can something like this be done?

Comment: Whenever you think you want this, what you actually want is an array!

Comment: Thank you, I learned my lesson!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you initialize `$rug_size` as an `array()`:

```
$rug_size[$i] = $_POST['Size' . $i];
```

If you really want to use different variable names (hopefully not):

```
$vn = 'rug_size' . $i;
$$vn = $_POST['Size' . $i];
```

Comment: Wow, this is a very simple and smart answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need wrap you dynamic variable within {} (and concat string with **Dot**), like:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
${"rug_size".$i} = "Hello world!";
echo $rug_size1;
?>
```

Output:

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: That doesn't work since it is inside of a for loop.  Unexpected {.

Comment: Using ${} is a way to create dynamic variables

Answer (score 2):

schould work like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$number_of_bundles; $i++) {
    $varname = 'rug_size'.$i;
    $$varname = $_POST['Size'.$i];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

do like this .

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$number_of_bundles; $i++) {

    ${'rug_size' . $i} = $_POST['Size' . $i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if i am not wrong than

```
$_POST['Size' , $i]
```

will be(i.e. dot instead of comma)

```
$_POST['Size'. $i]
```

another way to avoid error:**use isset()**

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$number_of_bundles; $i++) {
if(isset($_POST['Size' . $i]))
 {
  $rug_size . $i = $_POST['Size' . $i];
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I used a comma for my question. During my test I used the dot and it does not seem to work.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah are you sure u have input type's name as size1,size2 and so on?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Size with a capital S.

Comment: $rug_size . $i (as variable) should not work.If PHP really prompts undefined index I'll suggest you to check var_dump($_POST) or wrap it with a isset() checking.